# How to create a sinusoidal pattern in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, trigonometry

Following is my code to generate multiple images of sinusoidal fringe patterns with various shifts.

```matlab
f1 = 125; f2 = 100; N = 3;
x = linspace(0,pi*480, 640);
y = linspace(0,pi*640, 480);
[X0, Y0] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z1 = 0; Z2 = 2*pi*1/3; Z3 = 2*pi*2/3;
Teq = roundn((f1*f2)/abs(f1-f2), 2); p = 240;
im1 = 127 + 127*cos(2*f1*X0*pi + Z1);
im2 = 127 + 127*cos(2*f1*X0*pi + Z2);
im3 = 127 + 127*cos(2*f1*X0*pi + Z3);
im4 = 127 + 127*cos(2*f2*X0*pi + Z1);
im5 = 127 + 127*cos(2*f2*X0*pi + Z2);
im6 = 127 + 127*cos(2*f2*X0*pi + Z3);
```

In this case, if I use the above frequencies f1 and f2, I get the following

[image: Sine wave of two frequencies 100 and 125]

But if i use a frequencies f1 = 110 and f2 = 140, then I get the follwing sine wave which really looks weird.

[image: Sine wave with f = 110, 140]

Why is the period of second picture seems really weird?

The sine fringes are as shown in the following picture. The sine waves shown are taken at pixel y = 240

[image: Sine wave]

Comment: You have [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing), so the frequencies you "see" in the graph are not the actual frequencies. You should use smaller sample spacing or smaller frequencies to satisfy the [Nyquist criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_rate)

Comment: @dazemood I added a part of to my answer named `Final Script` that may achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: And how do you decide on the number of cycles? Does it depend on the frequency?

Comment: This worked wonders. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Just with the variable `Number_Of_Cycles`. Glad it worked. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Setting Number of Sample Points to Fit Sinusoidal Cycles

### Aliasing Preface:

[image: Aliasing Example]

Aliasing can occur when the sampling frequency used is not high enough to effectively sample the signal with high enough fidelity. An example of this can be sampling a signal that has a frequency of 100Hz. If this 100Hz signal is sampled at a rate of 100Hz you'll effectively see a straight line since only the peaks will be captured/sampled. Simply, the higher the sampling frequency the less ambiguous the sampled signal is. Using the Nyquist criterion can be a good base-point for determining the required frequency as described in the other comment above. You can use the below playground script to experiment.

### Playground Script:

```
%Plot 1%
Sampling_Frequency = 100; %Sampling frequency%
Sampling_Period = 1/Sampling_Frequency;

Start_Time = 0;
End_Time = 5;
t = (Start_Time: Sampling_Period: End_Time);

f = 2; %Frequency of sinusoid%
y = sin(2*pi*f*t);
subplot(2,1,1); plot(t,y,'-o');
title("Sinusoid Sampled at: " + num2str(Sampling_Frequency));
xlabel("t"); ylabel("Amplitude");
axis([Start_Time End_Time -1.2 1.2]);

%Plot 2%
Sampling_Frequency = 9; %Sampling frequency%
Sampling_Period = 1/Sampling_Frequency;

Start_Time = 0;
End_Time = 5;
t = (Start_Time: Sampling_Period: End_Time);


f = 2; %Frequency of sinusoid%
y = sin(2*pi*f*t);
subplot(2,1,2); plot(t,y,'-o');
title("Sinusoid Sampled at: " + num2str(Sampling_Frequency));
xlabel("t"); ylabel("Amplitude");
axis([Start_Time End_Time -1.2 1.2]);
```

---

Probably a good idea to use a multiple of `pi*480` in this case so that each cycle of the sinusoid (2π) has an equal number of sample points that nicely fit without aliasing. It is also a good idea to plot against another independent variable such as time, `t` so that you are not effectively plotting against the sample index/number. I wasn't totally sure what was the context of using `meshgrid()`. If you still need the replications using the `repmat()` function on `im1`,`im2`,`im3`,`im4`,`im5` and `im6` can allow you to create the additional rows you created transitively by using `meshgrid()`.

**Frequencies, f1 = 100 and f2 = 140:**
[image: Sinusoidal Plot]

In this case `5000*pi*480` samples were used.

```
f1 = 110; 
f2 = 140;

Number_Of_Samples = 5000*pi*480;
x = linspace(0,pi*480, Number_Of_Samples);

Z1 = 0;
Z2 = 2*pi*1/3;
Z3 = 2*pi*2/3;

im1 = 127 + 127*cos(2*pi*f1*x + Z1);
im2 = 127 + 127*cos(2*pi*f1*x + Z2);
im3 = 127 + 127*cos(2*pi*f1*x + Z3);
im4 = 127 + 127*cos(2*pi*f2*x + Z1);
im5 = 127 + 127*cos(2*pi*f2*x + Z2);
im6 = 127 + 127*cos(2*pi*f2*x + Z3);

clf;
plot(im1);   
hold on
plot(im2);   
plot(im3);   
plot(im4);   
plot(im5);   
plot(im6);   
xlim([0 1000]);
```

---

### Plotting with Respect to Another Variable:

Plotting with respect to another vector in this case time, `t`. Plotting with respect to another variable/vector lifts the constraints of plotting with respect to the sample index. If you take more samples it will not change the horizontal range since its range is determined by the vector, `t`. In this resolution of `480px by 640px` only so many cycles of a sinusoid fit before losing significant fidelity, especially for high-frequency sinusoids. Using the `imresize()` function helps to resize/decimate the image into the `480px by 640px` dimensions.

[image: Sinusoidal Fringe Image]

```
%******************************************************%
%PARAMETERS THAT CAN BE CHANGED%
%******************************************************%
f = 10; %Frequency of sinusoid%
Sampling_Frequency = 1000; %Sampling frequency%
Start_Time = 0;
End_Time = 5;
%******************************************************%

Sampling_Period = 1/Sampling_Frequency;
t = (Start_Time: Sampling_Period: End_Time);
y = sin(2*pi*f*t);
subplot(2,1,1); plot(t,y,'-o');
title("Sinusoid Sampled at: " + num2str(Sampling_Frequency) + "Hz");
xlabel("t"); ylabel("Amplitude");
axis([Start_Time End_Time -1.2 1.2]);

Image_Height = 480;
im1 = repmat(y,Image_Height,1);
im1 = imresize(im1, [480 640]);
subplot(2,1,2); imshow(im1);
title("Resized Image to be 480px by 640px");
xlabel("Width: 640px"); ylabel("Height: 480px");
```

---

### Final Script: Using the Number of Cycles to Simulate Sinusoids Frequency

This script simply uses the `Number_Of_Cycles` and transitively `End_Time` to adjust how much of the sinusoid is plotted for and then uses `imresize()` to get the `480px by 640px` image dimensions. The more of the sinusoid that is plotted the higher the frequency appears in the final image. This way you sample a low-frequency sinusoid with high fidelity and let `imresize()` decimate the sinusoid to the appropriate size and by plotting more or less of the sinusoid you can get more or less cycles within the image.

[image: Sinusoidal Fringe Pseudo Varying Frequencies]

```
Number_Of_Cycles = 50;
f = 1; 
Sampling_Frequency = 1000;
Start_Time = 0;
End_Time = Number_Of_Cycles*1/f;
Sampling_Period = 1/Sampling_Frequency;
t = (Start_Time: Sampling_Period: End_Time);
y = cos(2*pi*f*t);
Image_Height = 480;
im1 = repmat(y,Image_Height,1);
im1 = imresize(im1, [480 640]);
subplot(2,3,1); imshow(im1);
title(num2str(Number_Of_Cycles) + " Cycles in Image");


%Main parameter to adjust%
Number_Of_Cycles = 100;
End_Time = Number_Of_Cycles*1/f;
Sampling_Period = 1/Sampling_Frequency;
t = (Start_Time: Sampling_Period: End_Time);
y = cos(2*pi*f*t);
im2 = repmat(y,Image_Height,1);
im2 = imresize(im2, [480 640]);
subplot(2,3,2); imshow(im2);
title(num2str(Number_Of_Cycles) + " Cycles in Image");


%Main parameter to adjust%
Number_Of_Cycles = 5;
End_Time = Number_Of_Cycles*1/f;
t = (Start_Time: Sampling_Period: End_Time);
y = cos(2*pi*f*t);
im3 = repmat(y,Image_Height,1);
im3 = imresize(im3, [480 640]);
subplot(2,3,3); imshow(im3);
title(num2str(Number_Of_Cycles) + " Cycles in Image");


%Main parameter to adjust%
Number_Of_Cycles = 10;
End_Time = Number_Of_Cycles*1/f;
t = (Start_Time: Sampling_Period: End_Time);
y = cos(2*pi*f*t);
im4 = repmat(y,Image_Height,1);
im4 = imresize(im4, [480 640]);
subplot(2,3,4); imshow(im4);
title(num2str(Number_Of_Cycles) + " Cycles in Image");


%Main parameter to adjust%
Number_Of_Cycles = 20;
End_Time = Number_Of_Cycles*1/f;
t = (Start_Time: Sampling_Period: End_Time);
y = cos(2*pi*f*t);
im5 = repmat(y,Image_Height,1);
im5 = imresize(im5, [480 640]);
subplot(2,3,5); imshow(im5);
title(num2str(Number_Of_Cycles) + " Cycles in Image");


%Main parameter to adjust%
Number_Of_Cycles = 80;
End_Time = Number_Of_Cycles*1/f;
t = (Start_Time: Sampling_Period: End_Time);
y = cos(2*pi*f*t);
im6 = repmat(y,Image_Height,1);
im6 = imresize(im6, [480 640]);
subplot(2,3,6); imshow(im6);
title(num2str(Number_Of_Cycles) + " Cycles in Image");
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: In this case, I am trying to create fringe patterns and with resolution of 480x640. And the plot I had shown was just one vertical fringe from x = 240. I am sorry for not mentioning that. You think I can apply the same technique? And can you explain a little bit about aliasing? I am not sure I know the concept

Comment: If I understand correctly you're trying to make a sinusoidal fringe pattern that is an image. Then you must think in terms of the spatial domain. Do you have an example of an image what you're trying to achieve? Yeah sure, I'll elaborate on aliasing in my answer shortly.

Comment: @dazemood Are you looking to create something like this? https://github.com/MichaelTr7/StackOverflow/tree/master/Sinusoidal%20Fringe%20Pattern

Comment: So, I have 6 sets of images and i will attach it here. I want to find the wrapped phase of these fringes. When I use frequency of 200 and 225, then I find the sin fringes really good but when I use 210 as frequency, it is really weird. Which would possibly be because aliasing I assume.

Comment: Yes exactly like you have shown in the github. But for frwquency 210, mine looks really weird. I am not sure what I did wrong there.

Comment: I would proceed with my method an then just use `repmat()` to convert them into `480x640` images.

Comment: is it like combining the sin value with linspace and use repmat? Like the follwoing code? 

`im1 = repmat(sin(linspace(0,pi*100,640) + Z1),[480 1]);`
Like this?

Comment: Oh, I see the issue now, you want an image that is `480 by 640`. Unfortunately, 640 pixels is not enough pixels to sample a sinusoid of that frequency. An option may be to use more samples which leads to a larger image.

Comment: Even with that slight aliasing you probably still get a decent result though.